# What's best practice for designing a table with many access points in Dynamodb?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

So I am working on an application that is designed to be highly searchable - almost every field in the table will be querable. Let's call the table "job." It would look something like this in pseudo code:

```
  jobID: string
  accountID: string
  type: string
  keywords: Array<string>
  salaryLow: number
  salaryHigh: number
  numberOfApplications: number
  numberOfViews: number
  title: string
  postedDate: string
  description: string
  location: Location
```

So in this application, I would like to be able to order/query by all of these fields.  However, I'm wary of creating a global secondary index for all of these fields because that seems like it's an anti-pattern.  If I add an index for each of these fields, I believe that each write operation would take some time to be eventually consistent.

Currently, I have jobID setup as the partition key and keywords as the sort key but that doesn't make it very flexible for querying the other fields without resorting to a full table scan.

Can anyone give advice on this?  Very new to Dynamodb.  Thanks!

Comment: First of all, dynamoDb has a limit for the global secondary index - 5 per table, so you won't be able to create ones for each of these fields. And, I think for this purpose dynamoDb isn't the best choice. Actually, every global secondary index will create a separate table with his own write capacity and so on, and it will cost a lot, especially if you have a lot of create/update/delete operations.

Comment: If you don't need the low latency and scalability that DynamoDB provides, it might be better to look at other options. If you want to stay within AWS, one of the RDS databases would do the job. If want to stay with NoSQL, MongoDB, for example, has extensive indexing and text search capabilities; you could even create a separate index on the items in your keywords array.

Comment: Thanks - I think that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Again, DynamoDB isn’t the best solution if you want to use a single service. But it could be a great solution if you use it with ElasticSearch or even AWS CloudSearch.

You can create a DynamoDB Stream to forward the data updates in the table directly to CloudSearch. Then you just need to use the CloudSearch endpoint to make the queries and then recover the hash key or even show all values directly from CloudSearch.

I don’t know for sure, but maybe the CloudSearch will cost less than all the planned indexes...

Comment: This is the best solution if you are going with DynamoDB, where you can index attributes separately for the query using ElasticSearch or CloudSearch.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments as well, Dynamo wouldn't really be an ideal database for the problem. You would even end up overwriting a lot of data depending on the sort key and the partition key.

Looking at the columns, the ideal scenario would be to use something like Mongo and create indexes on the columns that need to be frequently queried.